# Average numeric

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a question: I want the average of some numbers. 
When I have 4 & 2 it says 3, that's correct but when I have 4 & 2.5 it says 14.50 ??

My code

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(round(100*(sum(My numbers) div count(My numbers))) div 100, '##.00')" />
```

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the XPath. Your script is probably reading other numbers. Post your full XSLT and source XML.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed @helderdarocha's comment, your xpath is working fine.

**XML**

```
<a><b>4</b><b>2.5</b></a>
```

**XSL**

```
<b><xsl:value-of select='sum(//b) div count(//b)' /></b>
<c><xsl:value-of select="format-number(round(100*(sum(//b) div count(//b))) div 100, '##.00')" /></c>
```

**GIVES**

```
<b>3.25</b>
<c>3.25</c>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged the question XSLT 2.0, so why aren't you using the avg() function?